# Unable to type into text field of Javascript form with Selenium / Python (element not interactable)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm using Selenium and coding with Python.

I'm trying to do the following: for a flight search website, under Flight 1's 'Enter routing code' text box, type 'AA'

This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
flight1_routing = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox_0']")
flight1_routing.clear()
flight1_origin.send_keys("AA")
```

But instead, I get this error message: "invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated". How can this be with a regular text field that is also not an autocomplete field, AFAIK?

Comment: Do you need to interact with the element you've provided? Can you manage using the 'id' "widget_advancedfrom1" upon which entering "AA" appears to activate the element that you wish to interact with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you get `Element is not currently interactable` check if the element is not disabled and its visible. if you want to `hack` it execute `JS` to enable it.

i visited the homepage `id ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox_0` doesnt exist also under flight one there's no `Enter routing code`. i can see the text box saying `airport city or city name`

Also if you have the id prefer to use `find_element_by_id` if not try to use `css selector` if you can rather than `xpath`. Its much cleaner.

***Update***

here's a working script:

As recomended above, the `elements` selected are not `visible`. what is actualy done, is that there's 5-6 different `elements` all hidden and when you click on show advanced route it picks 2 random ones and makes them visible.

So the `id` is not always the same. If you use the same id you will get a hidden `element` some times(because it picks random ids) so `selenium` is not able to deal with it. i made a selector that gets the 2 hidden `elements`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://matrix.itasoftware.com/")
#click on the multi tab
tab = driver.find_element_by_id("ita_layout_TabContainer_0_tablist_ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceForm_0").click()
#click on the advanced routes
advanced_routing=ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
     lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id("sites_matrix_layout_RouteLanguageToggleLink_1")
)
advanced_routing.click()
#get all visible elements with id like ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox. its similar to regex ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox.*
element = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        lambda driver : driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id*=ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceRow] [id*=ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox]")
)
element[0].send_keys("foo")
element[1].send_keys("bar")

import time
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you have to click on the 'Advanced routing codes' link first, which would enable that field. I forgot that this option is stored for me as default via cookies or something.

Comment: @Infection hi mate i got it working, i'll update my answer to explain how it works

Answer (score 0):

Did you click into the correct tab first & enable advanced routing codes?? e.g.

```
#Go to right tab
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#ta_layout_TabContainer_0_tablist_ita_form_multislice_MultiSliceForm_0 > span").click()
#Enable routing
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.itaToggleLink").click()

#note I seem to get a different id to the one you're using, assuming its dynamic numbering so handling all cases
#if you know how the dynamic numbering works youmay be able to deduce a single id that will work for your test case
#Instead I'm going for finding all elements matching a pattern then searching through them, assuming only one will be visible
flight1_routings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[id^='ita_form_location_RouteLanguageTextBox_']")
#probably better finding it then using it separately, but I was feeling lazy sorry.
for route in flight1_routings:
    if route.is_displayed():
        route.clear()
        route.send_keys("AA")
```

Also you can probably skip the .clear() call as it looks like the box starts with no text to overwrite.

Edit: Updated the enable routing toggling to handle not knowing the id, the class name stays the same, should work. Handling finding the input despite variable id as suggested by foo bar with the css selector, just then iterating over that list and checking if its on top

Comment: Hi Dave! I did indeed click through on the right tab first (sorry I didn't made this clear in my first post). This is really strange though, cos my IDs are different than yours - I'm not too sure what is wrong either. For instance, under "enable routing", my ID for that particular link under the Multi-city tab is `sites_matrix_layout_RouteLanguageToggleLink_0`

Comment: I would assume the id's are dynamically created on page load - and as you've got a different tab on first landing as a result of a cookie value you're getting different id's generated. So the first tab seen has the '0' id for its enable routing link, regardless of which tab that is. Hope that helps a bit... alternately you can use CSS selectors as shown above by foo bar to get a list of elements regardless of the number on the end and then pick the one which passes a .is_displayed() bool check. (If hitting the page with cookie set to the right tab that list will only contain one element)